# notification intent putextra method

Tags: android, notifications

I am working on a download manager . for managing notifications every second it calls two methods sequentially which build notification by getbroadcast . updateActiveNotification(downloads) And then updateCompletedNotification(downloads) . the first method checks my download list and builds an appropriate  notification which is supposed to show the download progress(it builds the notifications every second and so it looks like ongoing notification!) , the second one checks for completed downloads and builds their notifications. Now the problem is that I set data through putExtra in these two methods for both on-going download and completed downloads, but when I get the intents in my receiver I can't get the putExtra data from the completed download intents and actually the data keys are from the first method . 
I'm confused like hell! . these are two different methods which make different intents for different notifications . How is this possible.
Can anybody help me?!
Here is the example code :

first method :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(action);
Intent.setclass(receiver class)
intent.putExtra("someName1", boolean);
context.getbroadcast(intent);
```

second method :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(action);
Intent.setclass(receiver class)
intent.putExtra("someName2", boolean);
context.getbroadcast(intent);
```

now on reciever:

```
Bundle mybundle = intent.getExtras();
    if(mybundle != null) {
        for (String key : mybundle.keySet()) {
            //Object value = mybundle.get(key);
            Log.d("ALA-Dev", key);
        }
    }
```

for both intents (from the first method or the second one) it prints someName2 as the key ,meaning it dose's not get the second data at all!

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to give a qualified answer without code examples.  If you provided an extra like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, SomeActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("someName", someString);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Then you can get the data back using soemthing like this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String yourExtra = intent.getStringExtra("someName");
```